# How can i call an <ion-datetime> using an <ion-button>?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

im trying to perform the next action:

I just wanna select month and year with the next example:

```
<ion-datetime presentation="month-year"></ion-datetime>
```

But i dont want this label visible all the time, i think its way more convenient to call it using a button.

Is it possible?

I tried calling the datetime with:

```
<ion-datetime-button datetime="datetime"></ion-datetime-button>

<ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true">
  <ng-template>
    <ion-datetime id="datetime"></ion-datetime>
  </ng-template>
</ion-modal>
```

But i dont want to work with days/show them to the user.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little workaround for that. ion-datetime-button is not great indeed. I don't know why, but you still need it in the template to have a great looking modal when it open, but use 'display: none' on it.

And use the inline-modal isOpen property to open it with another button.

To get the date, you can use the (ionChange) methods on ion-datetime.

**HTML Template**

```
        <ion-button fill="clear" (click)="openCalendar()">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="calendar-outline" color="primary" size="small"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>

        <ion-datetime-button datetime="datetime" id="fake-click"></ion-datetime-button>
        <ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true" [isOpen]="showCalendar" (didDismiss)="cancelCalendar()">
          <ng-template>
            <ion-datetime
              id="datetime"
              presentation="month-year"
              [showDefaultButtons]="true"
              doneText="Confirm"
              cancelText="Cancel"
            ></ion-datetime>
          </ng-template>
        </ion-modal>
```

**TS file**

```
  openCalendar() {
    this.showCalendar = true;
  }
  cancelCalendar() {
    this.showCalendar = false;
  }
```

**CSS file**

```
#fake-click {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Dunno why you got downvoted - this is a great answer as `ion-datetime-button` is very restricted. This approach allows full control over the button and the modal.

Answer (score 1):

In ionic 7 like this :

```
 <ion-datetime-button datetime="dateBtn"></ion-datetime-button>

  <ion-popover  [keepContentsMounted]="true" alignment="center" mode="ios" 
   animated="false" >
    <ng-template>
      <ion-datetime id="dateBtn"
       preferWheel="false"
      [showDefaultButtons]="true"
      [cancelText]="'cancel' | translate"
      [doneText]="'setDate' | translate"
      presentation="month-year"></ion-datetime>
    </ng-template>
  </ion-popover>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Docs shows how to do this using [ion-datetime-button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime-button).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ion-datetime-button` that you already tried, but you have to keep the `ion-datetime`'s `presentation` property and set the value to use only the required ISO Date parts.

```html
<ion-datetime-button datetime="datetime"></ion-datetime-button>

<ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true">
  <ng-template>
    <ion-datetime
      id="datetime"
      presentation="month-year"
      value="2023-09"
    ></ion-datetime>
  </ng-template>
</ion-modal>
```

> Please read the [ISO Format](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v6/api/datetime#iso-8601-datetime-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmz) and the [Localization](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v6/api/datetime#localization) in the documentation for understanding about the value representation.